# Let function $f$ be defined by $f(X)$. Prove that $f$ is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let function $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be defined by $f(X) = \{2x+y\:|\:\langle x,y\rangle \in X\}$.
Prove that $f$ is bijective.

$\mathcal{P}(X)$  is a power set over $X$.

In order for function to be bijective, it has to be:

- 1-1: $f(\langle x_1,y_1\rangle) = f(\langle x_2,y_2\rangle) \Rightarrow \langle x_1,y_1\rangle = \langle x_2,y_2\rangle$
- onto: $\forall z \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \:\exists x,y\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}): f(x,y) = z$

To show that $f$ is 1-1, we take any $x_1, x_2\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$; $y_1, y_2\in \{0,1\}$ and we need to show that the first condition is true. Similarly, we need to show that the second condition is true, then it would mean that $f$ is bijective, though I do not know how to prove it step-by-step.
I also thought about other possible way of solving it. Function $h:A\rightarrow B$ is bijective iff it has an inverse function $h^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$, so I could think of a function which would satisfy this condition, but would it be a sufficient proof?

Comment: Yes, both approaches work. But you have to do it. It is not that difficult.

Comment: This is why I asked for help, I mentioned that I cannot prove it step-by-step using first method, as I do not know how should I start it and what I have to do next (sadly proofs are not my strong point). When it comes to the second method with finding the inverse function, I am trying to get it, but all my ideas were wrong.
I was thinking about $f^{-1}(n) = n$ for $n\in N$, but it does not contain whole $\{0,1\}$ set, as it is $f^{-1}(n) = n + 0$ in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Each $Y \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ has a unique decomposition $Y = Y_0 \cup Y_1$ where $Y_0$ contains all even numbers in $Y$ and $Y_1$ contains all odd numbers in $Y$. Define
$$Y_0' = \{ n/2 \mid n  \in Y_0 \} ,$$
$$Y_1' = \{ (n-1)/2 \mid n  \in Y_1 \} ,$$
$$g :  \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to  \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N} \times \{ 0,1 \}), g(Y) = Y_0' \times \{ 0 \} \cup Y_1' \times \{ 1 \} $$
and show that $g$ is an inverse for $f$.